# Third_party Views Path(s) Check in CodeIgniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to check if a view file really exists according to the third_party paths loaded

Normally, I'd check if a view exists with `is_file(APPPATH.'/views/folder/'.$view)`

I can retrieve every loaded third_party paths with [get_package_paths](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/loader.html#CI_Loader::get_package_paths) (thanks to the comment of Tpojka) and then check in their folder views if the file exists,

but I was hoping for a 'direct' check, as if the `->view` function would return `false` instead of redirecting to an error page

```
$html = $this->load->view($tpl,'',TRUE) ? $this->load->view($tpl,'',TRUE) : $another_template;
```

Though I realize there might be no other solutions that adding this manual check with a loop through the loaded paths and hide it in a CI_Load Class extension (application/core/MY_Loader) to give the apparance of a direct check in the controller:

EDIT: ***This is a bad idea, cause view() may return `false` to CI function that might not be designed for***

```
class MY_Loader extends CI_Lodaer{

public function __construct() {

    parent::__construct();

}

public function view($view, $vars = array(), $return = FALSE)
{
    foreach( $this->get_package_paths( TRUE ) as $path )
    {
        // this will only retrieve html from the first file found
        if( is_file( $path."/views/".$view ) ) return parent::view($view, $vars, $return);
    }
    // if no match
    return false;
}
}
```

What I find annoying is that load->view already makes a check through the paths, so this solution will add a second check and increase server consumption..

Comment: Could [get_package_paths](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/loader.html#CI_Loader::get_package_paths) help?

Comment: it's a good start, right, thanks for the hint ! Still I have to check manualy the files in the third_party view folder, but it definitly makes it easy to cross the results.

Comment: Acutaly in the end I think that what I'll do; Though I was hoping there's was kind of a direct check possible (maybe with extending the load->view ...)

Comment: I am glad I was able to point something useful although I don't get it why can't you use `is_file($file)`. You want to load package file if exists or main view file if package file doesn't exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well in the end I choose this lukewarm solution :

Instead of extending the function view() for it to return false (and having to deal with it through CI then after !) , I just made a function is_view() in the application/core/MY_Loader.php

I'm not sure MY_Loader is the correct place to place such a function, but so far it did the trick for me ...

(thx Tpojka for the indication)

in application/core/MY_Loader.php

```
/**
 * is_view
 *
 * Check if a view exists or not through the loaded paths
 *
 * @param   string          $view           The relative path of the file
 *
 * @return  string|bool     string          containing the path if file exists
 *                          false           if file is not found
 */
public function is_view($view)
{
    // ! BEWARE $path contains a beginning trailing slash !
    foreach( $this->get_package_paths( TRUE ) as $path )
    {
        // set path, check if extension 'php' 
        // (would be better using the constant/var defined for file extension of course)
        $path_file = ( strpos($view,'.php') === false ) ?  $path."views/".$view.'.php' : $path."views/".$view ;

        // this will return the path at first match found
        if( is_file( $path_file ) ) return $path."views/";
    }
    // if no match
    return false;
}
```

and in application/controllers/Welcome.php

```
$view = "frames/my_html.php";

/*
 *   the view file should be in 
 *   application/third_party/myapp/views/frames/my_html.php
 *   
 *   so far, if the file does not exists, and we try 
 *   $this->load->view($view) will redirect to an error page
*/

// check if view exists and retrieve path
if($possible_path = $this->load->is_view($view)) 
{
    //set the data array
    $data = array("view_path"=>$possible_path);

    // load the view knowing it exists
    $this->load->view($view,$data)
}
else echo "No Template for this frame in any Paths !";
```

and of course in the view

```
<h1>My Frame</h1>
<p>
    The path of this file is <=?$view_path?>
</p>
```